# Slight uneven forearms

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, arms, forearm

My left forearm is slightly smaller than my right.

Are there any bodyweight exercises I could do to even these out a little? I don't know how noticeable it is to others, but to me it is very noticeable.

Comment: R u at present doin any dumbbell exercise ?

Comment: Dis you wanted to say 'shorter' (shorter bones) or 'less muscular' (weaker than the other side)?

Answer (score 1):

Muscle imbalances are normal, nearly every adult has them, usually all over their body. People get injuries and don't recover perfectly, favor one side of their body, or via their vocations end up with weird body stuff.

There might be some more acute answer but if I were you I'd focus on regular strength training that promotes a balanced body. There are plenty of forearm strengthening exercises, notably anything that requires you to grab something and pull it up and down.

Here's a good video that goes over bodyweight forearm exercises, showing:

1) Finger hangs.

2) Finger pullups / pushups. (Sounds harder than it is, just adjust your angle).

3) Wrist pushes.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4H8S7PgLVwg